# Calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n ia_i}{n^2+n}$ given that $a_n \to a$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Calculate $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n ia_i}{n^2+n}$ given that $a_n \to a$.

I can see that if I can extract something from the sum the and have something multiplied by $\sum_i^n i = (n^2 +n)/2$ then stuff would cancel out, but I cant figure out what I can extract besides some arbitrary bound which won't converge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the converging sequence $\{|a_n-a|\}_n$ is bounded by some constant $M$. Moreover, for $\epsilon>0$, there is $N$ such that for $n> N$, $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$. Now recall that $\sum_{i=1}^n i=(n^2+n)/2$ and split the sum: for $n>N$
$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n ia_i}{n^2+n}-\frac{a}{2}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N i(a_i-a)}{n^2+n}+\frac{\sum_{i=N+1}^n i(a_i-a)}{n^2+n}.$$
Hence
$$\left|\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n ia_i}{n^2+n}-\frac{a}{2}\right|\leq M\cdot\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N i}{n^2+n}+\epsilon\cdot\frac{\sum_{i=N+1}^n i}{n^2+n}
\leq \frac{MN^2}{n^2+n}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$
Can you take it from here?

Another way: use [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem).

Comment: Won't this just show that it converges to something less or equal to M/2?

Comment: No, given $\epsilon$, $N$ is fixed and, as $n\to\infty$, the r.h.s goes to $\epsilon/2$

Comment: I think, as mentioned, Stolz-Cesaro theorem is clearly more directly applicable, which I thought of it almost as the first sight.

Comment: @RobertZ I see. Thanks!

Comment: @TonyMa That theorem is not in my syllabus so I would not be able to use but it's still good to know :)

Comment: Well... It is hard for me to learn according to syllabus... And it is not fun doing so

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, the idea behind this formula is:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i= \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

**Suppose first that $a = 0$**. You can write for $n > N \ge1$
$$\begin{aligned}
\left\vert \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n ia_i}{n^2+n} \right \vert &\le \frac{\left\vert\sum_{i=1}^N ia_i \right\vert}{n^2+n} + \frac{\sum_{i=N+1}^n i \vert a_i \vert}{n^2+n}\\
&\le\frac{\left\vert\sum_{i=1}^N ia_i \right\vert}{n^2+n} + \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n i \vert a_i \vert}{n^2+n}
\end{aligned}$$

Now for $\epsilon >0$, take $N$ large enough for having $\vert a_n \vert \le \epsilon/2$ for $n \ge N$. This is possible as we supposed $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n= 0$. Take then $M \ge N$ such that for $n \ge M$ you have 
$$\frac{\left\vert\sum_{i=1}^N ia_i \right\vert}{n^2+n} \le \epsilon/2$$.

This is possible as the numerator of the fraction is fixed, while the denominator tends to infinity. Finally for $n > M \ge N$ you get
$$
\left\vert \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n ia_i}{n^2+n} \right \vert \le \frac{\left\vert\sum_{i=1}^N ia_i \right\vert}{n^2+n} + \frac{\sum_{i=N+1}^n i \vert a_i \vert}{n^2+n} \le \frac{\left\vert\sum_{i=1}^N ia_i \right\vert}{n^2+n} + \epsilon/2 \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n i }{n^2+n} \le \epsilon$$

Proving that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n ia_i}{n^2+n} = 0.$

**Now for the general case** notice that
$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n ia_i}{n^2+n} - a/2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n ia_i}{n^2+n} - \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n i a}{n^2+n}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n i(a_i-a)}{n^2+n}$$
to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n ia_i}{n^2+n}=a/2$ using the case $a=0$.

Comment: Thanks this is very detailed! Wouldn't you need to use the fact that $a_n$ is bounded though to get rid of the $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N ia_i}{n^2+n}$ part (since for those indices $a_i$ is not less or equal to $\epsilon/2$)?

Comment: No because I **fix** $N$ and then use that $\lim n^2+n = \infty$. However, a converging sequence is bounded!

Comment: I see this is as the other answer for some reason I keep missing that N is fixed